# Adobe Analytics - Log/debug back-end traffic

Tags: adobe, analytics, web-analytics, adobe-analytics

I would like to confirm that I am sending the correct data to Adobe Analytics and I'm wondering if there is a possibility to log/debug the back-end traffic. I'm aware of Adobe Digital debugger, but I want to capture the back-end traffic also. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "back-end" traffic?

Comment: I mean the actual data that Adobe is inserting in to the reports and how is this information processed. We are having some weird issues with omniture and I think that this might help.

Comment: you can contact adobe client care and ask for hit data logs for a specified date range.  It will show the raw request urls sent to adobe, as well as some pre and post process data in columns (e.g. if you send a value into a variable but have a processing or vista rule affecting it, it will show a "before" and "after").

Comment: Thanks  Crayon Violent